# How to keep record of user logins in web app developed using Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php

I am building a web application in PHP using Symfony 1.4 and I want to keep record or user logins. Basically I should be able to tell how many times a particular user logged in and out in last week or last month. How can I do so? Is there a plugin for this? I am using sfGuard plugin. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seams like you can simply have a database table recording those fields.

I would propose this simple table structure:

```
id | user_id | login_time
```

Where id would be the primary and user_id would be an index.